# how to send email message to email added in our app

Tags: angular

i have add button in angular app which calls handle submit onClick. add adds the email in email list of app.i want to send email to email added that your xyz email has been added to our app. how do i approach this

```
  handleSubmit() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.sharedFolderDetails);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an automatic email to the newly added member, you will have to do it on server side, since your browser cannot send an automatic email on your behalf (it would be a major privacy issue).

This means you won't do it in your angular code.

If you are adding emails in the list, I assume that, at some point, you will send that new email to a remote server. When your server receives and processes that information, you will be able to implement your automatic email in the corresponding processing code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from the question, your approach should be like this:

Component ->  Service -> Backend (Send Email Service)

1. validate the email ids on the front end for the safer side.
2. Write a service in Angular, pass all email ids to the method
3. Service will call your backend passing all the email ids
4. Backend should handle sending actual emails.
5. After sending all the emails, return a boolean value from the backend which will be used to notify on front end that the operation is successful.